# No @interface for CalculatorViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, calculator

**This is the error that appears for both the 'double result' and 'if' at the bottom.**

Not sure why this is happening, it is from an Itunes U lecture and as far as I can tell from scanning it multiple times it is exactly the same.

### The Problem

***No visible @interface 'CalculatorViewController' declares the selector 'enterPressed'***

```
#import "CalculatorViewController.h"
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"

@interface CalculatorViewController()
@property (nonatomic) BOOL userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CalculatorBrain *brain;
@end



@implementation CalculatorViewController

@synthesize display = _display;

@synthesize userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber = _userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber;

@synthesize brain = _brain;

- (CalculatorBrain *)brain {
    if(!_brain) _brain = [[CalculatorBrain alloc] init];
    return _brain;
}

- (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender 
{
    NSString *digit = sender.currentTitle;

    if(self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber){

    self.display.text = [self.display.text stringByAppendingString:digit];

    } else {

        self.display.text = digit;

        self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber = YES;

    }
}

- (IBAction)enterPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.brain pushOperand:[self.display.text doubleValue]];
    self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber = NO;
}

- (IBAction)operationPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    if(self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber) [self enterPressed];
    double result = [self.brain performOperand:sender.currentTitle];
    NSString *resultString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", result];
    self.display.text = resultString;
}

@end
```

Comment: Post code from `CalculatorBrain.m` & `CalculatorBrain.h`

Answer (score 2):

You've got:

```
if(self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber) [self enterPressed];
```

Change it to:

```
if(self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber) [self enterPressed:self];
```

You're getting an error because you've forgot the parameter for `(id)sender` as you declared it in `enterPressed`.

```
- (IBAction)enterPressed:(id)sender
```

Comment: To clarify, `enterPressed` is a different method from `enterPressed:` (with the colon at the end). You've declared the method with the colon, but called one without.

Comment: Ok great! any idea why this section 'double result = [self.brain performOperation: sender.currentTitle];' isn't working and displays the same error?

Comment: Update your question with the code from `CalculatorBrain.m` & `CalculatorBrain.h`, or more specifically, your code for `performOperation` and I'll have a look.

Comment: If I had to guess, it is that you didn't declare your method in your `CalculatorBrain.h`.